# Docker scan step is failing on pipeline with login error

Tags: docker, gitlab, pipeline, runner, snyk

I am trying to use docker scan command in gitlab CI. I am loggin in to docker hub using docker login command and after that I am running docker scan --accept-license :. On my local machine everything works fine, but pipeline failing with this error:

**failed to get DockerScanID: You need to be logged in to Docker Hub to use scan feature.
please login to Docker Hub using the Docker Login command**

Anyone could help to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is informing you what the issue is: you need to authenticate with Docker Hub before you can access authenticated functionality. [The Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) highlight multiple ways of doing this.

Some options:

- Authenticate using the `docker login` command directly: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#options
- Use a proper credentials store: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store